# Sphinx adds documentation for NumPy modules to my docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to generate Sphinx documentation for my Python code. This code makes some imports from `numpy`. I use `sphinx-apidoc` on mycode and then run `make html`. It generates the documentation, but also it includes the documentation for `uniform` function from `numpy` in it. How to disable such redundant inclusions?

Here is my code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
"""
This module does blah blah.
"""

from numpy.random import uniform  #WHY IS IT INCLUDED IN SPHINX DOC?!!!!

class UberMegaClass(object):
    """Hell yeah!"""
    def __init__(self, num_of_something):
        print("---")
        self.num_of_something = num_of_something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Sphinx's handling of C++ extensions; they can be
included into documentation unnecessarily. There is a semi-official
[workaround](http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules) advising you to replace these modules with `Mock` objects
in your `conf.py`, like this:

```
import sys

class Mock(object):

    __all__ = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Mock()

    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        if name in ('__file__', '__path__'):
            return '/dev/null'
        elif name[0] == name[0].upper():
            mockType = type(name, (), {})
            mockType.__module__ = __name__
            return mockType
        else:
            return Mock()

MOCK_MODULES = ['pygtk', 'gtk', 'gobject', 'argparse',
                'numpy', 'numpy.random']
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = Mock()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way around that would be to change your rst.

```
 .. automodule:: module

 .. autoclass:: module.UberMegaClass
     :members:
     :undoc-members:
     :show-inheritance:
```

That outputs:

```
This module does blah blah.

class module.UberMegaClass(num_of_something)
    Bases: object

    Hell yeah!
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have already found a solution without modifying RST. The solution is to make a `Mock` on the C++  extensions that cause the errors, like `numpy` in my case.
Here it is:
http://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-import-errors-on-libraries-that-depend-on-c-modules